# Willie bot - parsing the rss and checking for a new post

Tags: python, bots, irc

I'm doing a module for my willie irc bot which makes the bot say a message whenever a new post appears in a given thread on a forum. The problem I have encountered is quite weird, actually: the bot returns an unhandled exception every once in a while:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function lurk at 0x10ebfa8c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 27, in lurk
    d=c.entries[0].published
IndexError: list index out of range
```

By every once in a while I mean exactly that: the error appears at random. Usually around 30 mins, but once it didn't appear at all for a whole 1,5 hour session. I have some ideas as to how I should handle this, but let's have a look at the bit of my code first:

```
import willie
import time
import thread
import feedparser
...
@willie.module.commands('startlurking')
def startlurking(bot, trigger):
    def lurk():
        bot.say("Right away, sir.")
        a=feedparser.parse('http://forums.wesnoth.org/feed.php?t=39175')
        b=a.entries[0].published
        while True:
            c=feedparser.parse('http://forums.wesnoth.org/feed.php?t=39175')
            d=c.entries[0].published #this is the line 27
            if not d==b:
                bot.say(trigger.nick + ", I have spotted a new post!")
                bot.say(c.entries[0].link)
                bot.say(c.entries[0].description)
                b=d
            time.sleep(10)

    thread.start_new_thread(lurk, ())
```

My first idea is that 10 seconds of sleep is not enough for my bot to parse the rss. Does anyone here know from their experience what time amount is 100% safe here?

Second idea is to ignore the error and make an exception that doesn't do anything, doesn't brake the loop and just retries the whole thing. Would this work?

```
try:
    #here goes the while loop
except:
    Pass
```

Which option is better in your opinion? I'd like to finally start coding in a "pro" way and not make noob work-arounds. If you have your own idea, please say it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your problem is that `feedparser.parse` isn't returning any entries. Instead of wrapping your entire while loop in a try except statement, I would make sure that more than 0 entries are returned.

I would replace `feedparser.parse('http://forums.wesnoth.org/feed.php?t=39175')` in your while loop with this:

```
import logging

...

c = feedparser.parse('http://forums.wesnoth.org/feed.php?t=39175')
if not len(c.entries):
    # You can use your own logger instance instead
    # Log any information you need to identify the real problem
    logging.error("No entries found: %s", str(c))
    continue
```

This should prevent the exceptions you were getting, with the added advantage of logging information so you can identify why you aren't getting any entries.

You can also do the same thing for your `feedparser.parse` call outside of the while loop, just replace `continue` with `return`.

Comment: This is what was logged as `str(c)`: `{'feed': {}, 'bozo': 1, 'bozo_exception': URLError(timeout('timed out',),), 'entries': []}` So I guess it's not my fault and it happens?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's much you can do about that. However now this problem shouldn't break your program. You can see more about `bozo_exception` [here](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/bozo.html#advanced-bozo).

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur where the `d.entries` list has no items. For instance in your console:

```
>>> entries = []
>>> entries[0]
... IndexError: list index out of range
```

To avoid this error just check if entries were found before proceeding.  For example you could change your loop to something like this:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    c=feedparser.parse('http://forums.wesnoth.org/feed.php?t=39175')
    if not c.entries:
        # no entries found, re-enter the loop at the "sleep"
        continue

    # entries found, process them...
```

Note I've moved `sleep` to the top

Comment: Well sorry but FastTurtle's answer is more helpful. I've used your advice on moving `sleep` to the top though, so I'll give you a +1 instead :)